# construct stacked dataFrame from 2D numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array with a shape (47365L, 14L), I would like to convert it into make 2 column dataFrame where the first column is the id, which is the number of the column in my original array and the second one is the data which is the content of the column like in the image below.

[image]

I tried this code buut without success.

```
    S.shape
    >>(47365L, 14L)
    IC_Label = ['sub_'+str(subNum) +'_IC_'+str(i) for i in range(0,S.shape[1])]
    ICA_df=pd.DataFrame(data=S, columns= IC_Label)
```

output:

```
        sub_1_IC_0  sub_1_IC_1  sub_1_IC_2  sub_1_IC_3  sub_1_IC_4 ............sub_1_IC_13
    0   -0.002277   -0.003315   -0.001300   0.000283    0.000473
    1   -0.004442   0.002921    0.000517    -0.000033   0.000349
    2   -0.003370   0.006067    0.002504    -0.000359   0.001467
    3   0.000075    0.004708    0.000087    -0.000176   0.002561
    .
    .
    47364
```

My data looks like this:

```
    ('MyData', array([[ -2.27721244e-03,  -3.31485020e-03,  -1.30029316e-03, ...,
     -1.33952356e-03,   2.93513841e-03,   1.22486268e-03],
   [ -4.44161427e-03,   2.92134270e-03,   5.17394574e-04, ...,
     -1.42587472e-03,   4.74996003e-03,   2.86699268e-03],
   [ -3.36958390e-03,   6.06671900e-03,   2.50417650e-03, ...,
      3.80042801e-03,   4.77244983e-03,   2.82142774e-03],
   ..., 
   [  3.57952033e-04,  -3.55516707e-04,   1.32481754e-03, ...,
      7.55565993e-03,   1.52018736e-02,  -4.67047470e-03],
   [ -2.07206006e-03,   6.60686763e-04,   2.04637699e-03, ...,
      7.94521155e-03,   1.50024315e-02,  -4.88461803e-03],
   [  1.43106607e-03,  -1.77342544e-03,   4.57835186e-05, ...,
      5.55311541e-03,   1.61148688e-02,  -4.63583610e-03]]))
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add data sample of your input?

Comment: @jezrael please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need select second values of tuple by `[1]`, `DataFrame` constructor and last [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1]).add_prefix('sub_1_IC_')
print (df)
   sub_1_IC_0  sub_1_IC_1  sub_1_IC_2  sub_1_IC_3  sub_1_IC_4  sub_1_IC_5
0   -0.002277   -0.003315   -0.001300   -0.001340    0.002935    0.001225
1   -0.004442    0.002921    0.000517   -0.001426    0.004750    0.002867
2   -0.003370    0.006067    0.002504    0.003800    0.004772    0.002821
3    0.000358   -0.000356    0.001325    0.007556    0.015202   -0.004670
4   -0.002072    0.000661    0.002046    0.007945    0.015002   -0.004885
5    0.001431   -0.001773    0.000046    0.005553    0.016115   -0.004636
```

And then use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a[1]).add_prefix('CL_').melt(var_name='id', value_name='data')
print (df.head(10))
     id      data
0  CL_0 -0.002277
1  CL_0 -0.004442
2  CL_0 -0.003370
3  CL_0  0.000358
4  CL_0 -0.002072
5  CL_0  0.001431
6  CL_1 -0.003315
7  CL_1  0.002921
8  CL_1  0.006067
9  CL_1 -0.000356
```

Another alternative with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for flattening with [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':a[1].T.ravel(), 
                   'id': np.repeat(np.arange(6), 6)}, columns=['id','data'])
df['id'] = 'CL' + df['id'].astype(str)
print (df.head(10))
     id      data
0  CL_0 -0.002277
1  CL_0 -0.004442
2  CL_0 -0.003370
3  CL_0  0.000358
4  CL_0 -0.002072
5  CL_0  0.001431
6  CL_1 -0.003315
7  CL_1  0.002921
8  CL_1  0.006067
9  CL_1 -0.000356
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have all value of a column stacked to each other and having the column's name as index